# Manage dependent input values in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, react-hook-form

I am developing a React application using react-hook-form `^7.47.0` and mui/material `^5.14.4`. I have a form input named `duration` that is a number which adds some days to a base date in order to update another form input named `due_date`. The user also can change the `due_date` input, so I have to get the difference between `due_date` and base date to update the `duration` input.
My `due_date` input:

```
<Controller
  name="due_date"
  control={control}
  render={({ field }) => (
    <DatePicker
      {...field}
      sx={{ width: '100%' }}
      slotProps={{
        textField: {
          size: 'small',
        },
      }}
      onChange={(v) => field.onChange(v)}
    />
  )}
/>
```

I don't know what is the proper way to update these dependent values.

**Approach 1:**
using `useEffect`:

```
const dueDate = useWatch({ control, name: 'due_date' });
  useEffect(() => {
    setDuration(differenceInDays(dueDate, props.operationDate));
}, [dueDate, props.operationDate]);
```

The problem is the `duration` input does not get updated after first changes in `due_date` input, and by changes in `due_date` for the next times, it gets **wrong** values.

**Approach 2:**

```
const dueDate = useWatch({ control, name: 'due_date' });
setDuration(differenceInDays(dueDate, props.operationDate));
```

I get the following error:

> Too many re-renders.

I also have a question related to react-hook-form that would be your kindness to answer:
The `useWatch` didn't give me the latest value of `due_date` until adding this line of code:

```
onChange={(v) => field.onChange(v)}
```

What does this line mean? How it solved the problem? Shouldn't the `useWatch()` give me the latest value since I added the `control={control}` to my input?